# Django admin set value of read only field from external service

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model whereby an id to store is generated by an external service, a 'job_id'. On creation, a post request is sent to this external service, and the job_id is sent back. The model is created only if this job_id is received.

Within the django admin, this job_id is set to read only, as this will be created by an external service. I have placed the request to the external service in the clean function:

```
    def clean(self):
        if not self.cleaned_data.get('job_id'):
            response = requests.post(external_service,
                                     params=params, data=data)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                raise ValidationError(_("external_service unavailable. Please try again"))
            self.cleaned_data.update({'job_id': self.__extract_job(response)})
```

However I cannot seem to add the job_id to the cleaned data, I keep getting:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: external_service.job_id
```

I have also tried

```
self.cleaned_data.setdefault('job_id', self.__extract_job(response))
```

but I cannot seem to attach the job_id data to the field.